# how to make SonarQube check JS code indentation

Tags: sonarqube, software-quality, sonarjs

I use a SonarQube 5.6.6 with sonarJS 3.3.0.5702 pluged on.

I am looking how to make my Sonar check the code indentation, i don't find rules for that on JavaScript.

Is my sonarJS version in cause ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no rule which allows you to verify code indentation (number of used tabs or spaces).

There are some rules which can help you a little bit to keep code more readable:

- [Tabulation characters should not be used](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-105)
- [Statements should be on separate lines](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-122)
- [Conditionals should start on new lines](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3972)
- [Function call arguments should not start on new lines](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1472)
- [Control structures should use curly braces](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-121)
- [Multiline blocks should be enclosed in curly braces](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-2681)
- [Conditionally executed code should be denoted by either indentation or curly braces](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3973)
- [An open curly brace should be located at the end of a line](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1105)
- [Comments should not be located at the end of lines of code](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-139)
- [Lines should not end with trailing whitespaces](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1131)
- [Lines should not be too long](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-103)
- [Files should contain an empty newline at the end](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-113)

Answer (score 1):

There is no rules in SonarJS checking code indentation.

You can use [prettier](https://prettier.io/) for your project to ganantee right formatting